# Do not resize SWT table after adding rows

Tags: java, swt

I have a dialog that contains an SWT table and a button to add rows to the table, the table is defined as follows:

```
Table myTable = new Table(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI);
myTable.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 5));
```

when the rows don't fit the table height then a scroll bar is added, it looks like this:

[image]

This is exactly what I want, but if I close the dialog and open it again, then the height of the table is automatically increased to fit all the rows, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to maintain the same height when I close and open the dialog again and add the scroll bar if necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a `heightHint` on the `GridData` for the table:

```
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 5);

data.heightHint = 200;

myTable.setLayoutData(data);
```